# Why will this object never stop?

Tags: mathematical-physics

Suppose an object is initially at x = 0 and at rest. It is then acted on by a force F which depends on it’s position as follows

$$
F(x) = +\frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
Without any other forces acting argue why the object never stops. Also, how much energy will the object acquire as x → ∞?

Comment: Because there will always be a positive force acting on it?

Comment: Notice that [$\vec F=m\vec a$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_second_law) if $m$ doesn't change over time.  For the energy, recall that the kinetic energy of the object $E_k$ is solely provided by the work of $F$, and that [$W=\int \vec F\cdot d\vec s$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)#Work_done_by_a_variable_force).

Answer (score 0):

Using Newton's Law, $$m\ddot{x}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}=mv\frac{dv}{dx}$$

So separating the variables and integrating, we have $$\frac 12 mv^2=\arctan x+c$$

From the initial conditions, $c=0$ and as $x\rightarrow\infty$, $\arctan x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$

Therefore $v$ remains positive and so it continues to move, and the limiting value of the kinetic energy is $\frac{\pi}{2}$